# Laravel 5.4 - IIS 10.0 root route issue

Tags: iis, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.4 and deployed this to IIS 10.0.

The root route is not working on IIS but same is working fine for php artisan serve.

Below is my route:

> Route::get('/', function () {     return view('welcome'); });

Please reply what i need to change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May i know what's wrong in this code.Guys please comment your valid points before downvoting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule to your url_rewrite module, after that root route will start working.

```
  <rule name="Index Request" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true"> 
        <match url="^$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="index.php" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
  </rule>
```

Let me know if my answer if helpful for you.

Comment: it helps me lot ...save my life