Laravel Project deployment issue
I am using IIS for laravel. I succesfully installed laravel and also running it using localhost and remote IP with php artisan serve command. The issue is, the base folder is running smoothly, but whever I am creating a folder inside it with laravel codes, it shows not found. So the issue is, I cannot redirect it to the childer folder content where I have kept the website codes.
For your information:
The child project has no database connection hing, only a simple website built on laravel platform.
This is that I have wrote inside route/web.php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/MCS', function () {
    return "My Child Project";
});

MCS is my child project folder. To confirm the solution is able to find the folder, i wrote "My Child Project". and its returning properly. But I don't know, how to go further to show the default page inside MCS folder...

Have you looked at some related questions ? For example, this one seams to tackle this exact problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48563090/5784924

fyi, php artisan serve does not use IIS

If you're using another folder for the child project, then you'll need to remove the route, and make sure the folder is in the public folder. If you want to route it to another directory completely, then you'll have to mess with the IIS routing, not Laravel routing. I'm not familiar with IIS, so I could not tell you how to do that.

If you want to display the content of your laravel codes as childer folder content, you can try to use url rewrite in iis: Using the URL Rewrite Module.
